# Select inside select

Tags: sql

A newbie here. So please be kind :-)

I have 2 Tables namely `Item` & `Item Entries`. 
Relation is: `Item.No = ItemEntries.No`.

In `Item Entries Table` I have Columns as `Qty, Entry type, Purchase Amount, Sales Amount`
I like to have a report which shows as below,

`Item No.  | Opening Quantity  |  Purchase Amount | Sales Amount`

To calculate Opening Inventory I summed up the quantity field and the result is as expected. No problem in that. Now From that dataset I like to run a sub query which Calculates/Sum the Purchase amount for an Item that  is a part of first dataset and similarly for Sales Amount.

`Select(Item No.,Sum(IE.Quantity) As Quantity, Select(......Purchase Amount),Select(....Sales Amount)`

I hope I was able to clear my doubts to you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Something like :

```
SELECT ItemNo, sum(quantity), purchaseAmount, SalesAmount FROM Item i INNER JOIN ItemEntities ie on i.no = ie.no GROUP BY ItemNo, PurchaseAmount, SalesAmount;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe (if I understand what you want) that this is the solution to your problem

```
Select Item.No ,
    Sum(IE.Quantity) As Quantity,
    (Select(......Purchase Amount)) As ColumnName1 ,
    (Select(....Sales Amount)) As ColumnName2
```

Answer (score 0):

From your need to "sum the purchase amount for an item that is part of the first dataset and similarly for Sales Amount" I think what you're trying to achieve is one row for each item on the Item table with a sum for each of the Qty, Sales Amount and Purchase Amount.  If so, then you can simply use a 'group by' clause which groups results together which have matching values for the columns specified.

```
SELECT I.no, SUM(IE.qty), SUM(IE.purchase_amount), SUM(IE.sales_amount)
FROM item I JOIN item_entries IE 
ON I.no = IE.no
GROUP BY I.no;
```

See the [group_by_clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF20038) for more details and some examples.

N.B. The join from the item tables isn't strictly required in this example, but if you're producing a report I suspect you might want to get things like a description - in which case you'll need to add those columns to the group by clause too.

Answer (score 0):

You might need the sum of three columns from 
ItemEntries table(Qty,PurchaseAmount,SalesAmount) for each Item.No

```
Select A.No,
  Sum(B.Qty),
  Sum(B.Purchaseamount),
  Sum(B.Salesamount)
From Item A,
  Itementries B
Where A.No = B.No
Group By A.No;
```